# Magento Call Event And Observer Only for My Custom Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, controllers

I am Find A Solution to call event when my controller is run. I found solution but is working on every controller run

```
<global>
   <events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
     <observers>
            <controller_action_before>
                <class>Mycustom_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>myFunction</method>
            </controller_action_before>
        </observers>
     </controller_action_predispatch>
   </events>
</global>
```

I need to run myFunction when my Module Controller is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Solution. 
Good trick

```
<global>
  <events>
<controller_action_predispatch_mycustomcontrollerhandler>
 <observers>
        <controller_action_before>
            <class>Mycustom_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>myFunction</method>
        </controller_action_before>
    </observers>
 </controller_action_predispatch_mycustomcontrollerhandler>
```

For example I need to call event On Product listing Page
I use

```
 <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_list>
```